# VBA Class with Collection of itself

Tags: vba, excel, class

I'm trying to create a class with a `Collection` in it that will hold other `CASN` (kind of like a linked list), I'm not sure if my instantiation of the class is correct. But every time I try to run my code below, I get the error

> Object variable or With block not set

---

**CODE BEING RUN:**

```
If (Numbers.count > 0) Then
   Dim num As CASN
   For Each num In Numbers
      If (num.DuplicateOf.count > 0) Then   'ERROR HERE
         Debug.Print "Added " & num.REF_PO & " to list"
         ListBox1.AddItem num.REF_PO
      End If
   Next num
End If
```

---

**CLASS - CASN:**

```
Private pWeek As String
Private pVendorName As String
Private pVendorID As String
Private pError_NUM As String
Private pREF_PO As Variant
Private pASN_INV_NUM As Variant
Private pDOC_TYPE As String
Private pERROR_TEXT As String
Private pAddressxl As Range
Private pDuplicateOf As Collection



'''''''''''''''' Instantiation of String, Long, Range etc.
'''''''''''''''' Which I know is working fine


''''''''''''''''''''''
' DuplicateOf Property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get DuplicateOf() As Collection
   Set DuplicateOf = pDuplicateOf
End Property
Public Property Let DuplicateOf(value As Collection)
   Set pDuplicateOf = value
End Property
''''' What I believe may be the cause
```

---

Basically what I've done is created two `Collection`s of class CASN and I'm trying to compare the two and see if there are any matching values related to the variable `.REF_PO` and if there is a match I want to add it to the `cthisWeek`'s collection of class `CASN` in the `DuplicateOf` collection of that class.

Hopefully this make sense... I know all my code is working great up to this point of comparing the two `CASN` `Collection`'s. I've thoroughly tested everything and tried a few different approaches and can't seem to find the solution

**EDIT:**

I found the error to my first issue but now a new issue has appeared...

Comment: `Private pDuplicateOf As New Collection` inside your class, or instantiate the collection inside your class_Initialize method.  Unless you're adding an empty collection in the case where there are no duplicates, `pDuplicateOf ` will be `Nothing` (and you can't call `Count` on `Nothing`)

Comment: @TimWilliams So when creating a class, do I want to initialize all values to either `Nothing` or `Null`? Should I have a `Class_Terminate` as well? I'm obviously not creating my class properly here... Also, how would I check if a Collection is empty if I can't use `.Count` on `Nothing`?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a relatively simple fix to your Get method:

```
Public Property Get DuplicateOf() As Collection
   If pDuplicateOf Is Nothing Then Set pDuplicateOf = New Collection
   Set DuplicateOf = pDuplicateOf
End Property
```

**EDIT:** To address your question - "So when creating a class, do I want to initialize all values to either Nothing or Null? Should I have a Class_Terminate as well?"

The answer would be "it depends" - typically there's no need to set all your class properties to some specific value: most of the non-object ones will already have the default value for their specific variable type.  You just have to be aware of the impact of having unset variables - mostly when these are object-types.

Whether you need a `Class_Terminate` would depend on whether your class instances need to perform any "cleanup" (eg. close any open file handles or DB connections) before they get destroyed.

Comment: So to addon to your editted answer, if these are being loaded into a `UserForm` it might be a good idea to have a `Class_Terminate` correct? Or should I create a `UserForm_Unload` function that will clear these variables when the form closes. Correct me if I'm wrong but when the form closes it's just being hidden and actually "Unloaded"?

Comment: I don't think you need a class_terminate here unless your class object has a handle on a specific resource which should be freed up.  When variables go out of scope they are automatically cleaned up.